# This riddle's a breeze!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

At first I am rough, but I know how to chill.
I'm integral to NASCAR, yet mocked by the NFL.
I can create a new clause, yet summon an army.
Some know me as beer, but what am I broadly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Oh that's a fun one!

> you are a Draft

At first rough, but know how to chill

> A heavy draft could disturb things, but is cooing on a hot day

Integral to NASCAR, but mocked by the NFL

> Drafting behind cars / Drafting players

I can create a new clause, yet summon an army

> Rough drafts in writing/editing, or Drafting as in conscripting new military recruits

Some know me as beer

> As in draught beer fresh from the tap

But what am I, broadly?

> Not sure if this even requires an additional answer, but perhaps it refers to the [many other uses of the word "Draft"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft)

Comment: "At first I am rough" -> first (and other early) draft is often a rough draft. "Create a new clause" might be referring to legal writing. NFL fans have hold mock drafts, I guess (aka fantasy football)?

Comment: I think "At first I am rough" refers to the first revision of a piece of writing being called a "rough draft," actually.

Comment: I was thinking there wouldn't be too references to drafting an essay... and perhaps I was also stuck on the title, but the pairs don't necessarily connect, so you could be correct..

Comment: @rm-vanda I thought that too, which is why I kept looking and found the reference to legal drafting, the writing of clauses of contracts and laws in precise, formal language.